# How to make a link not inherit properties?

Tags: html, css

So I don't really know how to phrase this, but I'll give it a shot.

On my website I have a navigation bar on the left. The paragraph and link elements are styled in the CSS. Now I have one link in my navigation bar with a unique id (the only one) that I do not want to inherit from the navigation bar's CSS.

It looks something like this:

```
<nav id="leftbar">
  <a href="link" id="special" onclick="function()"></a>
  <p>Navigation area 1</p>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="link">Link 1</a>
    <a href="link">Link 2</a>
    <a href="link">Link 3</a>
    <a href="link">Link 4</a>
</nav>
```

So leftbar is styled in CSS as `nav#leftbar`. `<p>` is styled as `nav#leftbar p`. Links are styled as `nav#leftbar a` and `nav#leftbar a:hover`. Now I added a new block to my CSS using `#special`. But because it's a link element and it's inside the navigation bar tags, it still inherits all properties from `nav#leftbar a`.

Is there any way to change that, or do I have to move the link with the "special" id outside of the navigation bar tags? I'd rather not do this as it is part of the navigation bar, just different.

I also tried adding the CSS properties of `nav#leftbar a` to `#special` and change them to overwrite them, but it still prioritizes `nav#leftbar a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class to exclude the link with the `special` id:

```css
nav#leftbar a:not(#special) {
  color: red;
}

#leftbar a:not(#special):hover {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<nav id="leftbar">
  <a href="link" id="special" onclick="function()">Special</a>
  <p>Navigation area 1</p>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="link">Link 1</a>
    <a href="link">Link 2</a>
    <a href="link">Link 3</a>
    <a href="link">Link 4</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

so

```css
a:not(#special) {
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:24px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="">links</a>
<a href="">links</a>
<a href="" id="special">links</a>
<a href="">links</a>
<a href="">links</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is  that `nav#leftbar a` is much more specific than `#special`. The former contains one id and two tags, the latter just one id.

I would change the id `leftbar` to a class `leftbar` and also remove the tag name in front of it in css, so you would target `.leftbar a` and `.leftbar p`. Then `#special` is more specific because it contains an id. (Classes are more significant than tags, ids are more significant than classes.)

If you know that `#special` is always the first entry of `#leftbar`, you also could target it using something like `#leftbar a:first-child`, without the need for an id.

Comment: Yeah I've been having a hard time deciding whether I should use ID's or classes. I figure I should prefer ID's because most elements of my website are things only used once (like a navigation bar). But this is where switching it up comes in handy.